# Why Can't Read The File(doesn't display the data)?

Tags: c++, file

*i Want to get from the user his address and store it in **file.dat** then display these data
For Example:

```
                    First Name: joooooosh
                    Last Name: Mikeeeeee
                    Governorate: Gize
                    City: 6 October132
                    Area: 4th District
                    Street Name/NO. : Conrad, 42, Washington, D.C.
                    Mobile: 123456789
                    Building Name/No. : 833
                    Floor No. : 3
                    Apartment No. : 7
                    Nearest Landmark: Pharmacy*
```

and when read from file to display, doesn't show **any thing, Why?**
**this code is part from my project, This is my complete project [https://github.com/loai1929/Bookshop-Management-System.git](https://github.com/loai1929/helloworld.git)**
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;


class Adress
{
public:
    char area[50], first_name[20], last_name[20], governorate[30], city[20], street_name[100], mobile[15], building_name[20], floor_no[10], apartment_no[5], nearest_landmark[50];
    void dis_ad();
    void display_adress();
    void get_adress();
};

void Adress::get_adress()
{

    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tMy Address:-\n\n\t\t\tFirst Name: ";
    cin.getline(first_name, 20);
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tLast Name: ";
    cin.getline(last_name, 20);
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tGovernorate: ";
    cin.getline(governorate, 30);
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tCity: ";
    cin.getline(city, 20);
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tArea: ";
    cin.getline(area, 50);
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tStreet Name/NO. : ";
    cin.getline(street_name, 100);
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tMobile: ";
    cin.getline(mobile, 15);
    cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\tBuilding Name/No. : ";
    cin.getline(building_name, 20);
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tFloor No. : ";
    cin.getline(floor_no, 10);
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tApartment No. : ";
    cin.getline(apartment_no, 5);
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tNearest Landmark: ";
    cin.getline(nearest_landmark, 50);
}
void Adress::display_adress()
{

    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tFirst Name: " << first_name;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tLast Name: " << last_name;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tGovernorate: " << governorate;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tCity: " << city;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tArea: " << area;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tStreet Name/NO. : " << street_name;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tMobile: " << mobile;
    cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\tBuilding Name/No. : " << building_name;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tFloor No. : " << floor_no;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tFloor No. : " << apartment_no;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tNearest Landmark: " << nearest_landmark;
}
void Adress::dis_ad()
{
    ifstream iFile("shippingAddresses.dat", ios::binary);
    while (iFile.read((char *)this, sizeof(*this)))
    {
        display_adress();
    }
    iFile.close();
}
int main()
{
    Adress ad;
    ad.dis_ad();
}
```

Comment: I'd guess opening of `iFile` fails causing `read` to fail meaning your while loop body never executes

Comment: `sizeof(*this)`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин are you suggesting that's an error? It returns the size of the current object which i believe is the intended behaviour

Comment: object you're talking about is not POD and even with POD you need `#pragma pack(1)` to do things like this

Comment: object you can write (C structure) can't have functions

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you so mush, you are right, this it was the issue.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин thank you man, I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин you can have methods in a POD type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c. If the objects are being read and written by the same code you don't need to worry too much about padding

Comment: @AlanBirtles so you're thinkin this guy has functions in class but doesn't have constructor? even `some_stuff() {}`? source class from where he'd copypasted this has one for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If opening `iFile` fails then the call to `read` will also fail and the body of the while loop will never execute. You should check the file opens successfully before using it:

```
ifstream iFile("shippingAddresses.dat", ios::binary);
if (!iFile)
{
    std::cout << "open failed\n";
    return;
}
while (iFile.read((char *)this, sizeof(*this)))
{
    display_adress();
}
```

Note that `iFile.close();` is unnecessary as the destructor closes the file automatically